# TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, input-type

Soy nueva en pandas, y tengo un archivo "datos_logistica.csv" con una columna nombrada "sexo" el cual contiene los siguientes valores "Mujer","Hombre" ambos son cadenas (strings)

```
datos = pd.read_csv("datos_logistica.csv")
```

Pero al momento de aplicar len() metodo obtengo el siguiente error

```
datos["sexo"].apply(len) TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

No entiendo porque aparece que mi objeto es un flotante en lugar de un cadena, si esta claro que es la columna "sexo" solo posee cadenas

Comment: debes hacer `datos["sexo"].apply(lambda x: len(x))` o `len(datos["sexo"])`, si lo que quieres es sumar todos los datos del campo sexo utiliza la segunda, la primera no te servirá para nada (a menos que quieras obtener la longitud de los caracteres de la palabra)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el siguiente comando para evitar que pandas.read_csv infiera en el tipo de datos

```
datos = pd.read_csv("file.csv", dtype={"sexo": str})
```

Por otro lado podemos utilizar **astype(dtype)** el cual convierte la Series de Pandas al tipo dtype especificado.

```
datos["sexo"].astype(str).apply(len)
```

Answer (score 1):

Parece que al importar datos, Pandas decidió cambiar el tipo de datos, puedes convertir de tal manera:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([1.1, 2.2], columns=['sexo'])

print(df)
   sexo
0   1.1
1   2.2

df['sexo'].apply(str).str.len()
0    3
1    3
Name: sexo, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

por lo que veo quieres saber cuantos elementos contiene el campo `sexo`, para eso debes usar lo siguiente:

```
cantidad = datos["sexo"].count()
```

Si lo que quieres es contar dependiendo del sexo puedes hacerlo con el metodo `count()` y pasándole como argumento una `lambda`

```py
cantidad = datos["sexo"].count(lambda x: x=="Hombre")
```

Esto contara los campos los campos cuyo contenido sea `"Hombre"`